# Python tkinter how to get value from an entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a little thing in python like JOpenframe is java and I'm trying to make an entry box. That works fine but when I try to get the value and assign it to variable "t" nothing works. This is what I have:

```
def ButtonBox(text):
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x150")
    t = Label(root, text = text, font = ("Times New Roman", 14))
    t.pack()
    e = Entry(root, borderwidth = 5, width = 50)
    e.pack()
    def Stop():
        root.destroy()
        g = e.get()
    ok = Button(root, text = "OK", command = Stop)
    ok.pack()
    root.mainloop()
t = ButtonBox("f")
```

I've tried to make "g" a global variable but that doesn't work. I have no idea how to get the value from this, and I'm hoping someone who does can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot get the value from a already destroyed entry widget because you have already destroyed the root window before calling `e.get()`.  Also it is not clear what you want on the variable `g`.  Do you want to return the value, i.e. assign it to variable `t`?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I would like to assign the value to var t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the value of the entry box after `ButtonBox()` exits, you need to:

- initialize `g` inside `ButtonBox()`
- declare `g` as `nonlocal` variable inside inner function `Stop()`
- call `g = e.get()` before destroying the window

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def ButtonBox(text):
    g = ""   # initialize g
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x150")
    t = Label(root, text = text, font = ("Times New Roman", 14))
    t.pack()
    e = Entry(root, borderwidth = 5, width = 50)
    e.pack()
    def Stop():
        # declare g as nonlocal variable
        nonlocal g
        # get the value of the entry box before destroying window
        g = e.get()
        root.destroy()
    ok = Button(root, text = "OK", command = Stop)
    ok.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    # return the value of the entry box
    return g
t = ButtonBox("f")
print(t)
```